# Fastest way to get total block time?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(wt.wait_duration_ms) / 1000,0) AS TotalBlockTime_s
  FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS tm
 INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks as wt 
                                    ON tm.lock_owner_address = wt.resource_address
```

The above code gives me exactly what I need, but I noticed it is a bit slow on some of my servers (~6 seconds).

How else can I quickly get total block time on my servers?

To give an example.. if User1 has been running a query for 10 seconds, and two more Users come in and are blocked for 3 seconds each, I want the query to return 6 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(wait_duration_ms) / 1000,0) AS TotalBlockTime_s
FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
WHERE wait_type IN (
SELECT wait_type FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats
WHERE wait_type LIKE '%LCK%'
)
```

Not perfect, but the above should suffice.